# Объясните пожалуйста что происходит после строчки matrix[]

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
import scipy.spatial
import numpy as np
import re

with open("sentences", "r") as file:
    sentences = file.readlines()

i = 0
for sentence in sentences:
    sentence = re.split('[^a-z]', sentence.lower())

    # Rewrite sentence with removed empty strings '' after splitting
    sentences[i] = filter(None, sentence)
    i += 1

word_index = dict()
i = 0
for sentence in sentences:
    for word in sentence:
        if word not in word_index:
            word_index[word] = i
            i += 1

matrix = []
for sent_i in xrange(0, len(sentences)):
    matrix.append([0 for x in word_index])

    for word in sentences[sent_i]:
        word_i = word_index[word]
        matrix[sent_i][word_i] += 1

np_matrix = np.array(matrix)

distances = list()
for i in range(len(sentences)):
    distance = scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(np_matrix[0], np_matrix[i])
    distances.append((i, distance))

sorted_list = sorted(distances, key=lambda tup: tup[1])

print sorted_list[1][0], sorted_list[2][0]
```

Объясните пожалуйста что происходит после строчки matrix[].

Comment: Да объясните человеку несколько строк кода (если есть желание). Закрытие тут ни к чему. Тем более с явно "притянутой за уши" формулировкой "Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях.". И где же эти прения и дискуссии? Может кто-то привести что-то субъективное? А то аж интересно.

Comment: Что бы объяснить, что делается  "после строчки matrix[]" надо понимать, что именно этот скрипт делает. Понятно, что не сами вы его писали, то хоть дайте ссылочку, откуда содрали. Посмотрим, попробуем разобраться.